# I need to make a boot drive

Tags: boot, uefi, drive, gpt, rufus

but I need to create it with these configs
GPT partition scheme for UEFI computer
It is possible to do with rufus but it does not work in linux (I tried with wine) so somebody knows some program like rufus for linux
sorry for my incredible english

Comment: Do you want to create a live drive to test Ubuntu and if it works well, to install Ubuntu into an internal drive? Or do you want to install Ubuntu into an external drive?. Please notice that if you use a cloning tool, you need not create any partitions before, the cloning process will overwrite it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mkusb with GUI. It do more then what rufus does. Simple to use.

Find the below article: [mkusb - tool to create boot drives | help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

Comment: Please add details to your answer, for example a link and maybe some instructions too, for example how to install mkusb.

Comment: try with dus 12. It supports gui option.

Comment: om ok,but now i need to put a custom boot file but is read only

Comment: @Infinit, please explain what you have done, what you have now, and what you want. -- What custom boot file do you need to put? Why?

Comment: @Infinit, maybe a persistent live system would work for you? (I am only guessing.) Please explain, otherwise we can only guess, and we cannot help much.

Comment: @sudodus I was angry and decided to install a virtual machine just for rufus, it worked out but now it's just boot on grub2 screen, I went in the folders and I did not find the grub config file (it's a arch linux),is there a way to create?

Comment: @Infinit, we are no experts on Arch here at AskUbuntu. You may get better help at the Arch forum or via the well written wiki page of Arch linux. But I can give some general advice: It is often easier (and faster) to backup the important personal files (documents, pictures, multimedia files) and make a *fresh installation* than to repair a broken system.